# nvd3 related 'Get' requests fail in the demo project?

Tags: django, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am running the django-nvd3 demo project and see that the pie chart is not being displayed. 
I see that the following requests fail

```
GET http://localhost:8000/static/nvd3/src/nv.d3.css
GET http://localhost:8000/static/nvd3/src/nv.d3.css  show_graph:3
GET http://localhost:8000/static/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js  show_graph:5
GET http://localhost:8000/static/d3/d3.min.js
```

I have installed python-nvd3 and all its dependencies. Here is my configuration for settings file

```
    BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'components')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
)

BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
    'jquery', 
    'underscore', 
    'd3#3.3.6', 
    'nvd3#1.1.12-beta', 
)
```

What am I missing ??

Comment: did you solve it? I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

In a production environment you have to serve static files using a webserver of your choice. The comment in your settings inditactes that you're running a development server. In that case, it is sufficient to add `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` to your installed apps. When `DEBUG = True`, the `staticfiles` app will automatically serve static files found in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` or by the various `STATICFILES_FINDERS` using python to stream  the response.

Do not use this in a production environment, as it is inefficient and probably insecure.

Instead, use your webserver (Apache, IIS, gunicorn etc.) to serve static files. The `collectstatic` management command will collect all static files to a central location (your `STATIC_ROOT`). Then set up your webserver to serve static files from this location.

More information on how to do this can be found in ['Deploying static files'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/) and in the documentation of your webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think the problem is with BOWER setttings, since ideally this 'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder  should have automatically found all the static files required for nvd3 to work ?

Comment: @user1524625 Have you specified `BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings and have you run `./manage.py bower install`? Also, you _are_ serving your static files like I posted, right? How are the requests failing, a 404?

Comment: If you see 'STATICFILES_FINDERS' above,it has the 'Bower Settings'.
This is my  installed app settings
BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'd3#3.3.6',
    'nvd3#1.1.12-beta',
)